# Почему на сервере крутится много экземпляров приложения?

Tags: linux, .net, asp.net-core, docker, .net-core

На сервере запущен один экземпляр приложения web api на dotnt core внутри docker контейнера, но если выполнить команду htop то она показывает много запущенных экземпляров приложения, почему так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу так же заметить если выполнить команду `docker top` над контейнером где запущено приложение то там будет один экземпляр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Multithreading ?

Comment: Это потоки, относящиеся к одному-единственному экземпляру. Скройте потоки в настройках htop, чтобы лишний раз не путаться

Comment: Нажми `f5`. Станет понятнее?

Comment: @donRumata после F5 вид стал древовидный , но все ровно много одинаковых процессов, как будто все так же

Comment: Ну собсно как сказали выше - многопоточка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-умолчанию HTOP отображает список Light Weight Process (LWP), которыми в linux являются потоки. При создании процесса PID первого потока будет также PID всего процесса, но все последующие потоки также будут иметь собственный идентификатор, который и отображается в столбце PID. Чтобы скрыть потоки можно зайти в Setup (F2) -> Display Options и выставить галочки `Hide kernel threads` и `Hide userland process threads`. Также там есть опция для отображения потоков другим цветом `Display threads in different color`.

на верхнем скриншоте потоки подсвечены зеленым, на нижнем - скрыты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

*"Много запущенных экземпляров приложения"*, как вам кажется - это на самом деле, потоки ***одного*** приложения и в действительности, на сервере запущено только ***одно*** приложение, работающее в многопоточном режиме.

Для справки: Многопоточность — свойство платформы или приложения, состоящее в том, что процесс, порождённый в операционной системе, может состоять из нескольких потоков, выполняющихся «параллельно». [Источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

*Небольшой совет на будущее*: Используйте древовидный вид (F5), как сказали в комментариях, чтобы видеть, какие потоки относятся к тому или иному приложению.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не разбираюсь в linux, но где именно на картинке видно, что это потоки, а не процессы? Есть ссылка на документацию по этой утилите? У всех строк разный PID (Process ID?), то есть на первый взгляд кажется, что это разные процессы, а древовидный вид лишь показывает, что у них один и тот же родительский процесс.

Comment: Это есть процессы, но факт в том, что все они относятся к одному родительскому, то есть все они - потоки одного приложения. Автор вопроса думал, что все это - разные приложения и моей целью было объяснить, что это не так. [Документация](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html)