# Что за зверь жрет память? /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize

Tags: php, mysql, cpu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер на 2-х 20-ядерных процессорах. Всего одна mysql база, запись и чтение из пары таблиц весьма "активное" - около 100 запросов в секунду в пиковые часы.
Структура таблиц не сложная, в самой большой - около 30 полей. Индексы расставлены.
Более того - до переезда на более мощный сервер сайт пару лет без особых хлопот работал на 8-ядерном проце.
Сейчас танцую с бубном уже пару недель. MySQL с учетом нагрузки конфинурировали саппорты reg.ru. Периодически LA сервера скачет до 80 и выше, пару раз в сутки сайт становится недоступен на 10-30 минут, затем все "отвисает" и возвращается к "нормальной" LA=6...8 (Хотя по мне это тоже не нормально, на 80 то потоках).
В памяти постоянно висят процессы

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Обычно один-два, в момент пиковой нагрузки - картина ниже.
Что это за чертовщина, в каком направлении копать и что еще оптимизировать?

Comment: [Почему на сервере крутится много экземпляров приложения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086520/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1106560#1106560) Ну а насчет затыков - это надо профилировать запросы. *"MySQL с учетом нагрузки конфинурировали саппорты reg.ru"* - фейспальм...

Comment: ¿Зачем кстати было переезжать на более мощный сервер, если и на 8 ядерном работало?

Comment: Фейспалм понятен, но в моем случае они как "лучик свет" - сам пишу в конфиг то, чего в интернете пишут. Они "с пониманием" что то делают - хотя бы надежда есть)

Comment: Переезжали из за планов запустить второй проект на одном сервере. А сейчас не то чтобы второй запускать - первый спасти бы (

Comment: Следуя вашему первому комментарию,https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086520/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1106560#1106560 понял что "истиная" нагрузка, вероятно, не в данном процессе. Сейчас оценить сложно - LA "как на зло" упал до 4-х )

Comment: Попробуйте использовать те конфиги, что были, когда сервер был 8 ядерным. А вообще телепаты в отуске. Мало ли, эти саппорты reg.ru на таком жирном серваке взялись биток майнить...

Comment: дурацкий вопрос, а SHOW PROCESSLIST что показывает в моменты пиковой загрузки?

Comment: | 4214942 | sroom | localhost | parser | Sleep   |    1 |          | NULL                                                                                                     |
| 4214943 | sroom | localhost | parser | Sleep   |    1 |          | NULL                                                                                                     |
| 4214944 | sroom | localhost | parser | Sleep   |    1 |          | NULL

Comment: Большое количество спящих процессов